# Help with abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ where $i^2 =j^2 =k^2 =-1$, $-i=(-1)i,$ $1^2 =(-1)^2 =1$, $ij=-ji=k$, $jk=-kj=i$, and $ki=-ik=j$.

a) Construct the Cayley table for $G$

b) Show that $H=\{-1,1\}$ is normal to $G$

c) Construct they Cayley table for $G/H$

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward question. You need to tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: ...please...? And what have you done so far? What self work? Hopefully you won't begin posting questions and hoping somebody else does your homework for you...

Comment: i have done part a but am struggling with where to start with part b and slightly unsure about c

Comment: Add this in your question, (edit it) and add the approach to part a) which lead to ans.Also add MathJAx . See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you know how to construct the Cayley table, this should be relatively easy as most of the work is done by defining all terms and conditions above.  And for part b, just look at the conditions.  If normality is represented (crudely here) by ab=ba for a,b in G, what can you say about elements ij for example, or jk in your particular case here?

Comment: As for c, since you know (maybe not by proof yet) that H is normal to G, then what can you say about all elements in G when we do gH?  how about Hg?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because "this question does not show any effort." I would be happy to reverse my vote if you updated your question, though.

Comment: Note that we usually say $H$ is normal *in* $G$, not $H$ is normal *to* $G$.

Answer (score 7):

HINT:
a)  I'll get it started for you, using what we already know:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrr}
 * &  1 & -1 & i & -i & j & -j & k & -k \\
\hline
 1 &  1 & -1 &  i & -i &  j & -j &  k & -k\\
-1 & -1 &  1 & -i &  i & -j &  j & -k &  k\\
 i &  i & -i &  1 & -1 &  k & -k & -j &  j\\
-i & -i &  i & -1 &  1 & -k &  k &  j & -j\\
 j &  j & -j & -k &  k &  1 & -1 &  i & -i\\
-j & -j &  j & k  & -k & -1 &  1 & -i &  i\\
 k &  k & -k & j  & -j & -i &  i &  1 & -1\\
-k & -k &  k & -j &  j &  i & -i & -1 &  1\\
\end{array}
$$

EDIT: I filled in a bit more...

b)     $\forall g\in G$, what do you get when you do $gH = g\{1,-1\}$?  What about $Hg = \{1,-1\}g$?

c)  Now, with a) completed and b) shown, look at the structure of the Cayley table.  Do you see anything that relates your $gH$ and $Hg$ inherent in the structure of $G$? (There is a reason that I ordered the Cayley table in a) like I did...)

Comment: @Arkamis, That was my first one ever....argh...!!